# How to create standard input in jquery ui style?

Tags: jquery-ui

I use UI lightness theme. How to make standard input (without autocomplete) in the same style?

Comment: What styles are you talking about? I don't recall seeing any styles on a regular input.

Comment: I mean border, background, font etc. used in the input field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the `ui-autocomplete-input` class to your input.